# Getting Error with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am working on android game development using COCOS2D-x  and i am working in ubuntu environment.

I am Following this

---

http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

---

and my helloworld program runs when i changed it to native c i am getting the following error.

```
    17:12:59 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project SampleApp ****
/home/user/Folder/Softwares/android-ndk-r8e/bash /home/user/folder/Softwares/cocos2d/SampleApp/proj.android/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1 
Cannot run program "/home/user/Folder/Softwares/android-ndk-r8e/bash": Unknown reason

Error: Program "/home/user/Folder/Softwares/android-ndk-r8e/bash" not found in PATH
PATH=[/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/user/Folder/Softwares/android-ndk-r8e]
```

,  guide me what and where i am doing wrong

Comment: Did you find solution for this issue? in eclipse i'm getting Error: Cannot run program "/ndkr8e/android-ndk-r8e/bash": Unknown reason. If you get post answer hre. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the build_native.sh file of your cocos2dx Add the NDK path.

## paths

NDK_ROOT="E:\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8e"